# Unable to insert data into SQLite table

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

The following source code is giving me an error:

```
405 Method not allowed
```

when I am pressing [Submit] button.

1. Why is it happening?
2. How can I fix it?

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
import secrets
import string

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///filename.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


def get_random_string():
    return ''.join(secrets.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(7))


class job_queue(db.Model):
    job_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    unique_job_key = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    user_name = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True)
    input_string = db.Column(db.String(256))
    is_done = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)

db.create_all()


@app.route('/')
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        unique_job_key_str = get_random_string()
        user_name1 = request.form['user_name1']
        text1 = request.form['text1']
        is_done_bool = 0
        created_at_time = datetime.utcnow

        new_job = job_queue(unique_job_key=unique_job_key_str,
                            user_name=user_name1,
                            input_string=text1,
                            is_done=is_done_bool,
                            created_at=created_at_time)

        try:
            db.session.add(new_job)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            return "There was a problem adding new job!"
        # end try
    else:
        users = job_queue.query.order_by(job_queue.created_at).all()
        return render_template('bootstrap_table.html', title='Jobs', users=users)
    # end if


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**bootstrap_table.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div>
<form method="POST">
  <table id="input_panel1" class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
      <td>Username:</td>
      <td><input name="user_name1"></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Input:</td><td> <textarea name="text1" cols="40" rows="5" ></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Submit: </td><td><input type="submit"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</div>
<hr>
  <table id="data" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Job ID</th>
        <th>Job Key</th>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Input String</th>
        <th>Is Done?</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for job_queue in users %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ job_queue.job_id }}</td>
          <td>{{ job_queue.unique_job_key }}</td>
          <td>{{ job_queue.user_name }}</td>
          <td>{{ job_queue.input_string }}</td>
          <td>{{ job_queue.is_done }}</td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
{% endblock %}
```

**EDIT:** Stack Trace:

```
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\python.exe C:/git/funkclusterfrontend/bootstrap_table.py
 * Serving Flask app 'bootstrap_table' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 100-569-534
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Dec/2022 22:37:19] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
ERROR:root:SQLite insertion error!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1719, in _execute_context
    context = constructor(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 1072, in _init_compiled
    param = [
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 1073, in <listcomp>
    processors[key](compiled_params[key])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\sqlite\base.py", line 1003, in process
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\git\funkclusterfrontend\bootstrap_table.py", line 46, in index
    db.session.commit()
  File "<string>", line 2, in commit
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1451, in commit
    self._transaction.commit(_to_root=self.future)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 829, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 808, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 3383, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 3523, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 3483, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 456, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 630, in execute
    util.preloaded.orm_persistence.save_obj(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\persistence.py", line 245, in save_obj
    _emit_insert_statements(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\persistence.py", line 1238, in _emit_insert_statements
    result = connection._execute_20(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1631, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 332, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1498, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1725, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2043, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1719, in _execute_context
    context = constructor(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 1072, in _init_compiled
    param = [
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 1073, in <listcomp>
    processors[key](compiled_params[key])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\sqlite\base.py", line 1003, in process
    raise TypeError(
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input.
[SQL: INSERT INTO job_queue (unique_job_key, user_name, input_string, is_done, created_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: [{'is_done': 0, 'created_at': <built-in method utcnow of type object at 0x00007FFCB1E11650>, 'user_name': 'user_name1', 'input_string': 'SasASas', 'unique_job_key': 'cwyRgim'}]]
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Dec/2022 22:37:25] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [31/Dec/2022 22:37:25] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: `except: return "There was a problem adding new job!"` This is a _terrible_ way to handle an exception.  You're deliberately hiding the actual error.

Comment: @JohnGordon I agree. OP would benefit from adding `logging` statements, including a `logging.exception` inside of any `except` blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [allow the `POST` method](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/#http-methods) on your endpoint. By default endpoints allow `GET` only.

Try changing `@app.route('/')` to `@app.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])`.

Edit:

One more issue, "TypeError: SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input." caused by `created_at_time = datetime.utcnow`, i.e. setting the variable `created_at_time` to the function `datetime.utcnow` instead of a value returned by that function: `datetime.utcnow()`. According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) `datetime.now()` is preferred over `datetime.utcnow()`.

Comment: Fixed. But, now it is giving `"There was a problem adding new job!"`

Comment: @user366312 can you share the stack trace?

Comment: I don't know how to see stack-trace. I am using PyCharm.

Comment: Add an `import logging` to the top of your file and an `logging.exception()` to your `except` block. Logging is a Good Thing :)

Comment: You need to add some message argument to the call to `logging.exception()`. `""` should do for now, but better to put something meaningful for your own diagnostics :)

Comment: Plz, chcek the edit.

Comment: Just edited the answer with a solution to the second issue :)

Comment: @user366312 If/when all's well please upvote and accept the answer :)